# Flatten the map and associate values using Java 8 Stream APIs

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

Suppose that I have a map of a set of strings to an integer value:
`Map<HashSet<String>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>()`.

For example, the `map` is (*we assume no duplicate strings*):

```
{x,y}   ->  2
{z}     ->  3
{u,v,w} ->  4
```

How can I get `another_map` of type `Map<String, Integer>` as follows, using ***Java 8 Stream APIs***:

```
x -> 2
y -> 2
z -> 3
u -> 4
v -> 4
w -> 4
```

It looks like a `flatMap` operation, but how could I associate the Integer values with each String key appropriately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this creating intermediate `Map.Entry` objects like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
   .<Entry<String, Integer>>flatMap(entry -> 
       entry.getKey()
            .stream()
            .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s, entry.getValue())))
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Alternatively you may use any other pair/tuple type you have in your project.

Note that my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library supports handling such cases in more clean way (internally it's the same as above):

```
Map<String, Integer> result = EntryStream.of(map).flatMapKeys(Set::stream).toMap();
```

The [`EntryStream`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html) class extends `Stream<Map.Entry>` and provides additional helpful methods like [`flatMapKeys`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#flatMapKeys-java.util.function.Function-) or [`toMap`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#toMap--).